# Having problem in COUNT() function in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

*Question.* **Write a query that counts the number of 300lb+ players for each of the following regions: West Coast (CA, OR, WA), Texas, and Other (everywhere else).**

**I have written SQL code for this question. And showing the data but the data is not matching with the answer**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state IN ('CA','OR','WA') THEN 'West Coast'
            WHEN state = 'TX' THEN 'Texas'
            ELSE 'other' END AS "STATES",
            COUNT(weight) AS players_above_300lbs
FROM benn.college_football_players
WHERE weight>300
GROUP BY "STATES"
ORDER BY "STATES"
```

**The SQL code is written in the solution is:-**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state IN ('CA', 'OR', 'WA') THEN 'West Coast'
            WHEN state = 'TX' THEN 'Texas'
            ELSE 'Other' END AS arbitrary_regional_designation,
            COUNT(1) AS players
  FROM benn.college_football_players
 WHERE weight >= 300
 GROUP BY 1
```

**I always got confused in COUNT() function, If I am suppose to count the weight, why I it did not consider weight column as the argument of COUNT()**

**I have shared the table**
[image: The table of football_players_name]

**Please help!**

Comment: I suggest you create a small representative sample that you can easily test by hand then start working on your code issues. And publish this sample as text.

Comment: nb you should use backticks when you are aliasing as a column to be used in group by and order by

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?(Can you tag it please)

Comment: Hint : **HAVING** clause following GROUP BY expression

Comment: I have used the **HAVING** clause but it is throwing an error as (org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "college_football_players.weight" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function)

Comment: "why I did not consider weight column as the argument of COUNT()" - because it counts the number of *rows* actually. Any non-null expression would do as an argument with `*` used as an idiom. And BTW what's wrong with the result? Both queries look just fine.

Comment: Your query seems correct? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t4SeExeewndPPfwe1RmQSP/0

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms of the `count` aggregate function:

1. `count(*)`, which is SQL's way to write an argument-less aggregate function. This will count the number of rows, no matter what they contain.
2. `count(expression)`, which will count the number of rows for which `expression` is not a NULL value.

You want to count the number of table rows where `weight > 300`, so `count(*)` would be the proper solution.  It just so happens that in all rows where `weight > 300`, `weight` cannot be a NULL value, so `count(weight)` will produce the same result. So will `count(1)`, because 1 is never NULL.

In a way, all these three solutions are correct, since they are guaranteed to produce the same result. Still, I maintain that `count(*)` is the most natural and best solution, because

- You are not counting the *weights*, you are counting the *players* that have a certain property. Now a player is a row in the table of players, so you are counting the rows. This is what `count(*)` means.
- `count(*)` is the fastest of the three solutions, because it does not have to check its argument for NULLness. Both `count(weight)` and `count(1)` are slower, because they perform an unnecessary check if `weight` or `1` are NULL or not.

Comment: Okay, that I got this time
Thanks for clearing my doubt in COUNT()